# Prevent automatic scroll and scroll to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I know there are many similar posts, but still I haven't get to the code I need.

Basically, I want to make a presentation the first time the user scrolls down. For that, I want to prevent the default action of scroll and (if it's scrolling down) make an animation to the next div.

```
window.scrolledToRed = false
window.scrolledToGreen = false

window.scrollTo = (to, guard ) =>
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(to).offset().top
  }, 1000, =>
    window[guard] = true
  )

window.addEventListener 'wheel', (e) ->
  if (e.wheelDelta < 0)
    if (!window.scrolledToRed)
      scrollTo('.red', 'scrolledToRed')
    else if (!window.scrolledToYellow)
      scrollTo('.green', 'scrolledToGreen')
```

I've created a Fiddle that represents the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/pn6zqgwu/2/

When the user scrolls down the first time I want to take him to the red div and the next time to the green one.
None of the solutions I've tried really worked, since it was both "jumping" and scrolling where I want.

Any idea of how to solve the problem?

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to call e.preventDefault() to prevent browser default scroll behavior

Comment: The problem then is that it does not scroll with scrollTop: $(to).offset().top

Comment: I added e.preventDefault(), it seems to work. Here is link: https://jsfiddle.net/jmjb4wt4/

Comment: It seems I cannot scroll to the green one (or up again) once I've scrolled to the red div.

Comment: It's OK for me. Maybe you scroll too fast, the jquery animation is not finished, your variable window[guard] has not be executed. I just guess!

Comment: But that's the thing! :) It keeps waiting for the callback and if I try to scroll, It jumps from where the user was trying to scroll to the "fixed" div. I'm trying to achieve this without making the user wait.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a fiddle for you, you can make more checks and add animations

```js
var redTouched = false;
var greenTouched = false;

function scrollCb() {
  event.preventDefault();

  console.log(event.wheelDelta)
  if (event.wheelDelta < 0) {
   if (!redTouched) {
    $(window).scrollTop($('.red').position().top);
    redTouched = true;
  } else if (redTouched && !greenTouched) {
   $(window).scrollTop($('.green').position().top);
   greenTouched = true;
 } else if (redTouched && greenTouched) {
   window.removeEventListener('mousewheel', scrollCb)
 }
} else {
 window.removeEventListener('mousewheel', scrollCb)
}

window.addEventListener('mousewheel', scrollCb);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jacobjuul/b0k03wtr/